# Irreducible finite-state Markov Chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Could anyone help me with this?

Let $X_n$ be an irreducible Markov chain on the state space $S=\{1,\ldots,N\}$. Show that there exist $C<\infty$ and $\rho <1$ such that for any states $i,j$,

$ P (X_m \neq j, m = 0, \ldots, n | X_0 =i) \leq C \rho^n.$

Show that this implies that $E(T)<\infty$, where $T$ is the first time that the Markov chain reaches $j$. (Suggestion: There is $\delta >0$ such that for all $i$, the probability of reaching $j$ in some moment of the first $N$ steps, starting at $i$, is major that $\delta$. Why?)

I`ve already got the suggestion but i do not know how to apply it.

Answer (score 1):

Detailed supplement for @Aref's Answer:

Given the problem statement,
$$p_{ij}(n) =\mathbb{P} \left\{ X_m\ne j, \forall m=1,\cdots ,n|X_0=i \right\}$$
represents the probability that, starting from state
$i$, the process does not reach
$j$ in
$n$ steps. The complement of this is
$$\mathbb{P} \left\{ X_m=j, \exists m=1,\cdots ,n|X_0=i \right\}$$
which represents the probability that, starting from
$i$, the process reaches
$j$ within
$n$ steps.

The Markov chain is irreducible, meaning that
$$\forall i,j\in S=\left\{ 1,\cdots ,N \right\} , \exists n_{ij}<\infty ,\quad \text{s.t.}\quad  p_{n_{ij}}\left( i,j \right) =\varepsilon _{ij}>0,$$
i.e., **after a sufficiently large number of steps, the probability of reaching $j$ from any $i$ is non-zero**. Let
$$d=\max \left( n_{ij} \right) ,\quad \varepsilon =\min \left( \varepsilon _{ij} \right),$$
then the probability of reaching
$j$ from any
$i$ in
$d$ steps is at least
$\varepsilon$. Therefore, the probability of not reaching
$j$ from
$i$ in
$d$ steps is
$$p_{ij}(d)\leq 1-\varepsilon, \quad, \forall i,j\in S.$$

Now, consider the relationship between the probability of not reaching
$j$ in
$kd$ steps ($k\in N$), denoted as
$p_{ij}(kd)$, and the probability of not reaching $j$ in $(k−1)d$ steps, denoted as
$p_{ij}((k−1)d)$. Utilizing the properties of the Markov chain, we have
$$
\begin{split}
p_{ij}(kd)&=p_{ij}(d)p_{ij}((k-1)d)\\
&\leq (1-\varepsilon)p_{ij}((k-1)d)\\
&\leq \cdots\\
&\leq (1-\varepsilon)^{k}p_{ij}(0)\\
&=(1-\varepsilon)^{k}.
\end{split}
$$
Let
$d$ have quotient $k$ and remainder
$r$ when divided by
$n$, i.e., $n=kd+r$. Then,
$$\begin{split}
p_{ij}(n)&\leq p_{ij}(kd)\\
&\leq (1-\varepsilon)^k\\
&=(1-\varepsilon)^{(n-r)/d}\\
&\leq (1-\varepsilon)^{(n-d)/d} \\
&=C\rho^n ,
\end{split}$$
where we define $\rho=(1-\varepsilon)^{1/d}\in(0,1),C=1/(1-\varepsilon)<\infty$, and they are independ of $n$.

Comment: You’re using k two times, may be confusing

Answer (score 0):

Use this fact that if process has not hitted $j$ in $m$ steps, it's not hitted $j$ in $k$ steps where $k$ is greatest multiple of $n$ smaller than $m$.
In fact, if there is a $\delta$ such that beginning from each $i$, you have reached $j$ in $n$ (may be smaller) steps with probablity greater than $\delta$, then take $\rho = (1-\delta)^ {1/n} $  and $C = 1/\rho$. Then, the assertion just says that after $kn+r$ where $(0≤r<n)$ steps, the probablity of not reaching $j$, starting from $i$ is less than $\rho ^ {(k-1)n+r}$. and its obvious. In fact more is true; such probablity is less than $\rho ^ {kn}$ because of strong Markov property.